Need help integrating TradingView with Gemini using ChatGPT
I am looking for some assistance on how to integrate TradingView with Gemini using ChatGPT. I am trying to combine these platforms for some financial analysis and trading purposes, but I am having trouble figuring out the specifics of how to do this integration.
If anyone has experience with integrating TradingView and Gemini with ChatGPT or has any relevant information or resources to share, I would greatly appreciate your help.
Thank you in advance for your assistance.
Need help integrating TradingView with Gemini using ChatGPT

Please take the [tour] and learn [ask].
